# Illustrator and Javascript - Move pathItem to new layer

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I can't seem to find this in documentation, as the `pathItem` `layer` and `parent` members are read-only.  How do I programmatically change the layer of an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

select your pathItem programmatically
select your layer programmatically

```
myPathItem.move(myLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);
```

Comment: Much appreciated Fabian!